# Housewife UK Visit Visa Finance Questions

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am applying for UK visit visa for my mother, which is a housewife with no income and no savings. My mother is living with my father, who is covering all her day-to-day expenses and will also be fully sponsoring her trip to the UK. During the application process, I came through the following question:

Do you have another income or any savings? The options are:

1- Other regular income:

A-Allowance or regular money from your family
B-Pension
C-Investments
D-Another income.

2- Savings

3- I do not have any other income or savings

My question is: Should I select option (3), or should I use option (1) and declare my father's income (and if so, do i need to later say in the additional information part that this is my father's income).

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fairly common scenario.

Use option (1). Explain that your mother is financially dependent on your father in the section at the end of the visa application and submit your father’s bank statements and proof of the source of his income.

Comment: Thanks.

This answer will open up another issue. The next question on the application is: Does anyone rely on you for financial support?

Now, my 17 years brother relies on my father's financial support and my mother's support in his day-to-day activities (eating, studying, etc.). Does that mean I have to answer yes to this question, assuming that I am now presenting my father's income as money coming to my mother from family?

Ideally, I would say NO because it is my father whom my brother is relying on financially, but based on your suggestions, I am a little bit confused.

Comment: You’d answer *No*. UKVI are interested in establishing that a visitor has sufficient resources for the proposed trip and that the source of those resources is legitimate. The question isn’t asking about non-financial dependencies. Presumably a 17 year old will be able to manage without his mother’s support while she is away. Reading this https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1019544/Visit.pdf might help, if you’ve not done so already